# How do I remove padding from a framed box?

Tags: spacing, framed

I am unable to use `mdframed` on my server so I am currently creating a `framed` box like this:

```
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\small{
\noindent \textbf{Key Results}:blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah \\

\noindent \textbf{Implications}:blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
}
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to reduce the padding in this box so that it appears more like this?

[image]

Comment: What does the »[framed](http://ctan.org/pkg/framed)« manual say?

Comment: `\small` is a command without an `argument`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `\FrameSep0pt` to have no padding or an appropriate length to adjust.

Comment: This has to be done/changed *outside* the `framed` environment.

Comment: @Werner Obviously, like any length you need to set it before you use it.

Comment: When I use this macro, it just outputs "0pt". Not quite the effect I was looking for. :P Do you know why it doesn't work properly when I use it?

Comment: Never mind, I was using the `framebox` macro, not `framed`...

Comment: This also works for the ```shaded*``` environment.

Comment: How can I reduce the space/margin outside the framed box?